# How to store a payload value in a global variable - Objective-c

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

Is it possible to store a payload value into a global variable in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. In future, I need to use this global variable from javascript function(phonegap). notificationData is a global variable which i declared in .h file.

```
NSString * notificationData;
```

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in .m file

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    BOOL ret = [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
        //opened from a push notification when the app is closed
        NSDictionary* userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

        if(userInfo != nil){
             [self processRemoteNotification:userInfo];
        }
    } else {}

    return ret;
}

-(void) processRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSString *ctpayload = [userInfo objectForKey:@"payload"];
    notificationData = ctpayload;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. I think you already have it as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Why you save only reference for the payload. It is string you can allocate a new string with the payload value:

```
myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:payload];
```

and use it.
Declare

```
NSString* myString;
```

in .h file.